# How do I build an exit into python script running at boot?

Tags: shell-script, boot, python, raspbian

I use an rPi Zero running Raspbian for time-lapse photography. Upon boot a shell script is called that then launches a python script.

The python script takes x number of pictures then moves itself to another folder. This is so I can use the rPi in the field on battery power, power down and on next boot from home, the shell doesn't find the .py and therefore boots to desktop. I then copy the files I need, delete them from the pi and move the script back into the folder where it can be found again and power down, prepping for next use.

My question is; can I build an exit into this process so if my battery dies 3/4 of the way through the script in the field, I can still plug in at home and kill it so I can salvage the images.

Here are my scripts:

launcher.sh:

```
cd /
cd home/pi/bbt
sudo python bbt.py
cd /
```

bbt.py:

```
import shutil
import os
import time

FRAMES = 1000
TIMEBETWEEN = 10

frameCount = 0
while frameCount < FRAMES:
    imageNumber = str(frameCount).zfill(7)
    os.system("raspistill -o firstTLimage%s.jpg"%(imageNumber))
    frameCount += 1
    time.sleep(TIMEBETWEEN - 6)

shutil.move('/home/pi/bbt/bbt.py' , '/home/pi/bbt/TLbackup/bbt.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you not do this this way.  Using side effects like whether a file can be found by the startup code is just going to make things hard to debug, and hard to deal with things like error conditions (battery failure).  Your script should track the variables it is concerned with and then act accordingly.

Here is a recast of your script which looks to see if an image is are already present, and only if the image is not there will it take images.  It also adds a mechanism to make sure the time between shots is consistent:

```
import time
import os

FRAMES = 1000
TIMEBETWEEN = 10
FILENAME = 'firstTLimage % 07d.jpg'

if not os.path.exists(FILENAME % 0):
    next_time = time.time()
    for frame_count in range(FRAMES):
        time.sleep(max(0, next_time - time.time()))
        next_time += TIMEBETWEEN
        os.system("raspistill -o " + FILENAME % frame_count)
```

*NOTE:* I did not test this, so use as a template.